# Vectorization of numpy dot product throws Value Error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a function to calculate the dot product between two vectors and it works perfectly fine with single values

However when I try to vectorize this function using a pandas dataframe it throws a Value error

```
def find_dot_prod(pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6):
    a = np.array([pt1, pt2])
    b = np.array([pt3, pt4])
    c = np.array([pt5, pt6])
    
    ba = a - b
    bc = c - b

    return np.dot(ba,bc)
```

**This works:**

```
find_dot_product(2, 6, 7, 9, 11,12)
# -29
```

**This doesn't Works:**

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'pt1':[4,5,6,7,9,8,1,12,18,7],'pt2':[9,4,3,5,11,14,15,5,9,7]})
df['dot_prod'] = find_dot_product(df['pt1'], df['pt2'],
                       df['pt1'].shift(), df['pt2'].shift(),
                       df['pt1'].shift(2), df['pt2'].shift(2))
```

**Error:**

```
ValueError: shapes (2,10) and (2,10) not aligned: 10 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

Comment: Read the `np.dot` docs.  The last axis of A must match the 2nd to the last of B!  A (2,10) works with a (10,2).

Comment: @hpaulj Do you mean we have to transpose the Matrix B. Something like this np.dot(A,B.T)

Answer (score 0):

I think `np.dot` not working well with missing values, so you can use:

```
def find_dot_prod(pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6):
    a = np.array([pt1, pt2])
    b = np.array([pt3, pt4])
    c = np.array([pt5, pt6])
    
    ba = a - b
    bc = c - b

    return  np.nansum(ba * bc, axis=0)


df= pd.DataFrame({'pt1':[4,5,6,7,9,8,1,12,18,7],'pt2':[9,4,3,5,11,14,15,5,9,7]})
df['dot_prod']  = find_dot_prod(df['pt1'], df['pt2'],
                       df['pt1'].shift(), df['pt2'].shift(),
                       df['pt1'].shift(2), df['pt2'].shift(2))

print (df)
   pt1  pt2  dot_prod
0    4    9       0.0
1    5    4       0.0
2    6    3      -6.0
3    7    5       1.0
4    9   11     -14.0
5    8   14     -16.0
6    1   15     -10.0
7   12    5      87.0
8   18    9     -26.0
9    7    7      74.0
```

Verify last row:

```
print (find_dot_prod(7, 7, 18, 9, 12,5))
74
```